# How to Copy Entire Word Document Contents to Email body using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python3, I have been able to copy contents from txt file and paste it to email body and eventually send the email. Now similarly, I require to copy entire contents of word doc e.g. .docx contents to email body

My Input doc file is shown below and it also contains one hyperlink in blue(I need that to be copied as it is)
[Input Word Document Content which needs to be copied to Email Body as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFsCQ.jpg)

I tried below code but no success

```
    def main():
            names, emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.txt') # read contacts
            message_template = read_template('message.docx')
```

Error I got while running python code is:

```
C:\Users\windowsmachine\PycharmProjects\selenium\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/windowsmachine/PycharmProjects/selenium/testmichael.py
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/windowsmachine/PycharmProjects/selenium/testmichael.py", line 76, in <module>
                main()
              File "C:/Users/windowsmachine/PycharmProjects/selenium/testmichael.py", line 42, in main
                message_template = read_template('message.docx')
              File "C:/Users/windowsmachine/PycharmProjects/selenium/testmichael.py", line 36, in read_template
                template_file_content = template_file.read()
              File "C:\Users\windowsmachine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
                (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
            UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 15: invalid start byte

            Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is actual code used for the project https://gist.github.com/arjunkrishnababu96/5c96ef3306b92120696a44b92db8947f

```
import smtplib

from string import Template

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

MY_ADDRESS = 'my_address@example.comm'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

def get_contacts(filename):
    """
    Return two lists names, emails containing names and email addresses
    read from a file specified by filename.
    """

    names = []
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            names.append(a_contact.split()[0])
            emails.append(a_contact.split()[1])
    return names, emails

def read_template(filename):
    """
    Returns a Template object comprising the contents of the 
    file specified by filename.
    """

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        template_file_content = template_file.read()
    return Template(template_file_content)

def main():
    names, emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.txt') # read contacts
    message_template = read_template('message.txt')

    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='your_host_address_here', port=your_port_here)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)

    # For each contact, send the email:
    for name, email in zip(names, emails):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

        # add in the actual person name to the message template
        message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())

        # Prints out the message body for our sake
        print(message)

        # setup the parameters of the message
        msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
        msg['To']=email
        msg['Subject']="This is TEST"

        # add in the message body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

        # send the message via the server set up earlier.
        s.send_message(msg)
        del msg

    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
    s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: .docx files are not plain text files and cannot be read like .txt files. If you want to read Rich Text Format use PyRTF. Im not sure how to read .docx though. EDIT: theres maybe this library but ive never used it -> https://pypi.org/project/docx/0.2.4/  alternatively use something to convert the docx to plain text and just pass that to your working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use docx2txt for read that kind files , like this ...first install docx2txt   : pip install docx2txt

```
import docx2txt
text = docx2txt.process("Doc2.docx")
print(text)
```

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/mymachine/PycharmProjects/selenium/testmichael.py", line 2, in <module>
    import docx2txt
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx2txt'

   Process finished with exit code 1'

Comment: pip install docx2txt

Comment: yeah i did even restarted my pycharm ide

Comment: And If you try in your console? I mean in the cmd

Comment: You got it it works from console ,i am confused why not woking in Pycharm

Comment: its working thanks ,opened a new project in pycharm